# favicon won't load only in safari but in other browsers it does

Tags: html

does anybody know what could cost the problem of favicon not loading in safari? In chrome and firefox it's working just fine... ( the icon is in png)[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you
use this:

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="{{ base_path }}/images/safari-pinned-tab.svg?v=M44lzPylqQ" 
 color="#000000">
```

Comment: great it works, but do you know how I can keep the icon colored?

Comment: I think css will work for colouring